# pandas_datareader reader giving error on getting financial data

Tags: python, pandas-datareader

This code should return me bitcoin market data between the two dates. However it is give an error.

TypeError: string indices must be integers

can anyone spot what I am doing wrong here?

```
import datetime
import pandas_datareader as pdr

# Get the current date and time
now = datetime.datetime.now()
df = pdr.get_data_yahoo("BTC-USD", start="2020-01-01", end="2021-01-01")
print(df.head())
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the complete error report starting with the word **traceback**. You can surround the report with 3` before and 3` after to properly format the output.

Comment: I would also check the result of the request from yahoo